# OpenWrt opkg update Signature check failure

Tags: openwrt

I have a TP-Link router. TL-WDR4300. I have setup OpenWrt environment in it.

Version details is as follows:

Linux version 4.4.14 (alex@AlexPC) (gcc version 5.3.0 (OpenWrt GCC 5.3.0 50108) )

I used the following command

```
 root@OpenWrt:~# opkg update


Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/Packages.gz.
Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/Packages.sig.
 Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/kernel/Packages.gz.
Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/kernel/Packages.sig.
Signature check failed.
 Remove wrong Signature file.
 Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci/Packages.gz.
Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci/Packages.sig.
Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/management/Packages.gz.
  Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/management/Packages.sig.
Signature check failed.
  Remove wrong Signature file.
 Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages/Packages.gz.
 Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages/Packages.sig.
 Signature check failed.
 Remove wrong Signature file.
 Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/routing/Packages.gz.
 Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/routing/Packages.sig.
 Signature check failed.
  Remove wrong Signature file.
  Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/telephony/Packages.gz.
  Downloading "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/telephony/Packages.sig.
  Signature check failed.
  Remove wrong Signature file.




   Collected errors:
      * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/Packages.gz, wget returned 8.
   * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/Packages.sig, wget returned 8.
    * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/kernel/Packages.gz, wget returned 8.
       * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/kernel/Packages.sig, wget returned 8.
    * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci/Packages.gz, wget returned 8.
    * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci/Packages.sig, wget returned 8.
     * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/management/Packages.gz, wget returned 8.
    * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/management/Packages.sig, wget returned 8.
    * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages/Packages.gz, wget returned 8.
   * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages/Packages.sig, wget returned 8.
   * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/routing/Packages.gz, wget returned 8.
   * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/routing/Packages.sig, wget returned 8.
   * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/telephony/Packages.gz, wget returned 8.
   * opkg_download: Failed to download "http"://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/telephony/Packages.sig, wget returned 8.
```

Can anyone solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got this working on my Orbi:

```
sed -i -re 's/^(option check_signature.*)/#\1/g' /etc/opkg.conf
mv /usr/bin/wget /usr/bin/wget.bin
```

Then create **/usr/bin/wget** with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/wget.bin --no-check-certificate "$@"
```

And finally **chmod +x /usr/bin/wget**

```
root@SRR60:/etc/ssl/certs# opkg update
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/bcm53xx/generic/packages/base/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/opkg-lists/chaos_calmer_base.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/bcm53xx/generic/packages/luci/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/opkg-lists/chaos_calmer_luci.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/bcm53xx/generic/packages/packages/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/opkg-lists/chaos_calmer_packages.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/bcm53xx/generic/packages/routing/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/opkg-lists/chaos_calmer_routing.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/bcm53xx/generic/packages/telephony/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/opkg-lists/chaos_calmer_telephony.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/bcm53xx/generic/packages/management/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/opkg-lists/chaos_calmer_management.
```

Comment: Perhaps first it would be better to check the date of the router. If the client's date is too off from the server's date, an encrypted connection cannot be established.